# electron sql.js Uncaught TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string

Tags: node.js, buffer, electron, sql.js

I've created a little script with sql.js documentation, but i'm unable to write buffer into a.db (Win) 
console gives me error: "Uncaught TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string"
is that something regarding "var data = db.export();" function or is there something wrong in my code?

```
var fs = require("fs");
var remote = require('remote');
var SQL = remote.require('sql.js');
var file = "a.db"
var exists = fs.existsSync(file);

if(!exists) {
console.log("DB creation: "+file+ "");
fs.openSync(file, "w");
}

var filebuffer = fs.readFileSync(file);

// Load the db
var db = new SQL.Database(filebuffer);
// Run a query without reading the results
db.run("CREATE TABLE test (col1, col2);");
// Insert two rows: (1,111) and (2,222)
db.run("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?), (?,?)", [1,111,2,222]);

var data = db.export();
var buffer = new Buffer(data);
fs.writeFileSync(file, buffer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var SQL = remote.require('sql.js');
```

Why are you doing a remote require here? `sql.js` is not a built-in main-process module, so there's no reason you can't do a regular `require('sql.js')` in your renderer-process. You should be very careful about using the `remote` module, since serialization across process boundaries may have undesirable side-effects (which are documented in the [API docs](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.36.5/docs/api/remote.md)).

Comment: Hello,
because an error of stdout of sql.js i've used remote, but is seems not the right way, so i've used sql-debug.js instead if sql.js and i've commented out these lines and app works fine:
`if (ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB && preloadStartTime !== null) {
  Module.printErr('pre-main prep time: ' + (Date.now() - preloadStartTime) + ' ms');
}`
when the application is executed on windows by double-clicking on the .exe file (compiled version) the error is triggered because of the line written in the console, which is not present on Windows unless the application is launched using the prompt

Comment: Have you tried doing `process.stdout.write = console.log.bind(console);` before requiring `sql.js`?

Comment: @VadimMacagon I did `process.stderr.write = console.error.bind(console);
process.stdout.write = console.log.bind(console);
var SQL = require('sql.js');`
and it worked. (I'm using Electron.) Thanks for the suggestion!